# No scalar data was found in tensorboard

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

i can not work well with tensorboard, here are my codes

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

sess=tf.InteractiveSession()

x_data=np.random.rand(100).astype('float32')
y_data=x_data * 0.1 + 0.3
w=tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1], -1.0, 1.0))
b=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
y=w * x_data + b 
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - y_data))

train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(loss)
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess.run(init)

loss_summary = tf.scalar_summary('loss', loss)
writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('.../test', sess.graph)

for step in range(100):
    sess.run(train)
    if step % 10 == 0:
        print step, sess.run(w), sess.run(b)
```

Here is my file hierarchy:

```
|--cnn
|  |--my_codes.py
|  |--test
|  |  |--events.out.xxx
```

Under the cnn dictionary, i type:

```
tensorboard --logdir=/home/.../test (absolute path)
```

however, i get 'no scalar data was found'. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to tensorflow and trying tensorboard.
May be try giving a valid path in the SummaryWriter like

writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('/home/user/cnn/test', sess.graph)